# Addition of two matrix using struct

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, struct

I'm trying to sum two matrix using struct, but it doesn't work.

If this code can be optimized please tell me :D

Compile with:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall program.cpp -o program
```

Output:

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from Proy3.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:548:5: note: template std::basic_ostream& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream&, const unsigned char*)
     operator<<(basic_ostream& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:548:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Proy3.cpp:51:30: note:   ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_ostream’
             cin << &M2.x[i][j];

Code:

```
# include < cstdio >
# include < iostream >


typedef struct Matrix
{
    int row, column;
            int x[20][20];
};

Matrix M1,M2;
```

using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
cout << "Insert size rows: Mat[a]";
cin >> M1.row);

cout << "Insert size of columns Mat[a]";
cin >> M1.column;


cout << "Insert size of rows Mat[b]";
cin >> M2.row;

cout << "Insert size of columns Mat[b]";
cin >> M2.column;

int i, j;

   // Matrix x

    for(i = 0; i <= M1.row; i++)
{
        for(j = 0; j <= M1.column; j++)
        {
        cout << "Insert number for matrix X : \n";
        cin >> M1.x[i][j]
        }
}

       // Matrix y

    for(i = 0; i <= M2.row; i++)
{
        for(j = 0; j <= M2.column; j++)
        {
        cout << "Insert number for matrix Y : \n";
        cin << M2.x[i][j];
        }
}

// Matrix X + Matrix Y

for(i = 0; i <= M1.row; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < M1.column; j++)
    {
        cout <<"The sum of " << M1.x[i][j] << " + " <<  M2.x[i][j] << " = " << M1.x[i][j] +  M2.x[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for(i = 0; i <= M2.M1.row; i++)
 {
    for(j = 0; j <= M2.M1.column; j++)
    {
    cout << "Insert number for matrix Y : \n";
    cin << &M2.M1.y[i][j];   
    }
  }
```

There is no element as `M2.M1.y` which you are trying to access.
Also why are you declaring `M1` inside `M2`.You could have only one structure and have two instances of it.Something like

```
struct matrix
{
    int row,column;
    int X[20][20];
};
struct matrix M1,M2;
```

Now you can input the two matrices.

Also you have to use `cin>>a` instead of `cin>>&a`.

Also `cin << &M2.x[i][j];` should be

```
 cin >> M2.x[i][j];
    ^^^^
```

Comment: Ok,I made the changes but now prints a lot of :/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:530:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Proy3.cpp:51:30: note:   ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>’
             cin << &M2.x[i][j];
                              ^
while is trying to compile

Comment: You don't use `cin>>&a`.You use `cin>>a`

Comment: I make the changes but still getting the same output :/

Comment: omg... Hahahaha, that little mistake.. Almost makes me crazy xD, Thank you very much for your help and time, appreciate it :D

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cin state ment should be cin >> &M2.x[i][j]; instead of cin << &M2.x[i][j];